# Is there any benefit to receiving LinkedIn recommendations from colleagues/class fellows?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, linkedin

Do LinkedIn recommendations from your colleagues or class fellows matter to hiring managers? And does it matter that it would be from classmates or colleagues instead of from seniors or people with high achievements?

I am an iPhone developer, and let's say I get a recommendation from an Android or a .Net developer who was my class fellow. Would this add some value to my profile?

Reply from experienced hiring managers and HR would be appreciated.

Comment: HR doesn't care about anything on your resume or linked in profile. They're not usually the people making the hiring decisions.

Comment: @DA then who does?

Comment: Usually a hiring manager. And I imagine that, while Linked in 'meta info' wouldn't hurt, it's likely not a high priority in whether or not they decide to hire you.

Comment: @DA. HR are usually the gate keepers for the hiring managers, so they do have some influence.

Comment: It can't hurt. Also, recruiters use LinkedIn to find candidates, and if they see recommendations and endorsements it is likely to make them more interested in you.

Comment: @workerBoy - I don't think it makes much of a difference, unless its from someone like jon skeet or bert bates. Sometimes, people just hand out recommendations randomly to their friends or colleagues without even knowing if the receiver is worthy. So, i would say that it depends on who recommends you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LinkedIn is more of a long term approach than a short term one. Add your classmates now, and you'll be less likely to lose track of them over the next 20 years. And perhaps 20 years from now someone will be impressed by who you're connected to.

Typically once you've come to the attention of a company (say, by applying for a job) your LinkedIn profile won't be used for much more than verification: you say you went to University of X, I see you're connected to dozens of University X graduates, you probably went there. The "recommendations" feature is in my opinion, just silly. People endorse me for skills I really have, skills I had when they last worked with me ten years ago, and "joke" skills in technologies I hate because that's funny. I can't imagine any hiring manager looking over two resumes and decided which one to interview based on LinkedIn recommendations. Even the one-or-two sentence endorsements "X is a treat to work with and one of the smartest people I have ever met" are hard to evaluate since they could well have been written by your mother or your best friend. If you're able to get a famous person who is clearly not your mother or best friend to endorse you (say I could get Bjarne Stroustrup to say something nice about my C++ skills) then don't waste that positive energy on LinkedIn - get it on your blog, twitter, facebook and generally shout it from the mountaintop.

Set yourself up on it, connect to everyone you can, and keep it up to date for long term payoff, but don't worry about immediate benefits as a new graduate.

Comment: recommendations you _receive_ are typically out of your control, that's right. But those you _give_ are under your full control - I for one use this to expose _whom_ I worked with, along with _how_ it went. :) _"`X`'s strong design skills, combined with profound technical knowledge and with top notch abilities to innovate make a perfect mix for interesting work. I enjoyed every "software adventure" in which we collaborated. He is honest, helpful and very reliable. Great partner to work with..."_ (the only caveat it takes me from week to month to write a rec)

Comment: @gnat interesting approach!

Comment: Kate, I picked just the shortest of recs I wrote, to fit the comments length limit. You've got to see my longer "essays" - full of details, hidden self-promotion and all the buzzwords :)

Comment: yeah, I agree it all depends on who gives the recommendation.